# Do not get proper value in tableview from few rows first

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];
//NSMutableArray *values=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[LoginResult allValues]];    
NSMutableArray *statenameArray=[LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];
for(NSDictionary *countname in wholeJsonArray)
{

    NSString *cName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[countname objectForKey:@"country_name"]];
    [countryArray addObject:cName];

}
for(NSDictionary *cid in wholeJsonArray)
{

    NSNumber *number = [cid objectForKey:@"country_id"];
    [idcountry addObject:number];
}

for(NSDictionary *statename in statenameArray)
{

    NSString *sName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[statename objectForKey:@"state_name"]];
    [stateArray addObject:sName];
}
```

I wrote the above code.

Country name is displayed properly in table view. State name response also gets displayed but few rows display have null value and other rows proper value. So what should i do to remove null value from few rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing the name, id and state name in different arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *countries = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];

for(NSDictionary *country in countries){

    NSString *countryName = country[@"country_name"];
   if(countryName)
        [countryArray addObject:countryName];

    NSNumber *countryId = country[@"country_id"];
    if(countryId)
        [idcountry addObject:countryId];

    NSString *stateName = country[@"state_name"];
    if(stateName)
        [stateArray addObject:stateName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last `for` with this:

```
for (NSDictionary *statename in statenameArray) {
    NSString * sName = [statename objectForKey:@"state_name"];
    if (sName.length > 0) {
        [stateArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sName]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add state strings to array only if it's valid.

```
for(NSDictionary *statename in statenameArray)
{
   NSString *sName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[statename objectForKey:@"state_name"]];
   if (sName!=nil && sName.length!=0) {
     [stateArray addObject:sName]; 
    }
}
```